# Power Bi Reports embedding without exposing the config settings

Tags: c#, powerbi, razor-pages

I'm working on client side embedded Power Bi reports and I found out that it exposes config setting properties such as accessLevel and viewMode which can be edited when you inspect the page. That would enable the Users to edit reports even if it is not created by them.
My question is, is there a way to access the report's config settings on the server side and set their properties from there?

I tried encrypting the config settings but it's useless because the last line of code is `powerbi.embed(reportContainer[0], decryptedConfig);` but it still exposes the decryptedConfig settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The embedding configuration can be changed in Javascript only in "Embed For Your Organization", where the end user is using their own identity and permissions to access Power BI.

In "Embed for your customers" the embedding configuration is generated on the server side using an application identity and is signed to prevent client-side tampering.

See generally: [Understanding the different embedding solutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/embedding-solutions)

Comment: Thanks David for this information. Does that mean we have to buy an additional license for premium account?

Comment: If the users have Pro licenses you can use either embedding style.  There’s a limit on how many embed tokens one user can create to enforce this.  So the app should use the user’s access token to generate the embed token.